# Emit custom gtk signal with variable as user data

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I want to send a custom signal with user data. The user data (coming from a `GtkEntry`) is not filled upon connecting the signal, but is when the signal is emitted.
How can I emit a signal with the content of a `GtkEntry` as user data?

Right now I have a signal handler for the "standard" signal `button_press_event`. This handler reads the `GtkEntry`'s and emits the custom signal. This is where I want de `GtkEntry` data to be sent as user data.

I **do not** want to send a pointer to `GtkEntry`, since the `GtkEntry` belongs to `login_credentials_screen.c`

I have a UI file:

```
<!-- Generated with glade 3.38.2 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.24"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow">
    <property name="can-focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can-focus">False</property>
        <property name="halign">center</property>
        <property name="valign">center</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel">
            <property name="height-request">80</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">False</property>
            <property name="halign">center</property>
            <property name="valign">center</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Enter the correct user code
and company code to log in</property>
            <property name="justify">center</property>
            <style>
              <class name="text_large"/>
            </style>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkBox">
            <property name="height-request">40</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">False</property>
            <property name="halign">center</property>
            <property name="valign">center</property>
            <property name="margin-top">5</property>
            <property name="spacing">20</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkEntry" id="user_code_input">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can-focus">True</property>
                <property name="placeholder-text" translatable="yes">User code</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkEntry" id="company_code_input">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can-focus">True</property>
                <property name="placeholder-text" translatable="yes">Company code</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEventBox" id="login_button">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">False</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkLabel">
                <property name="width-request">250</property>
                <property name="height-request">60</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can-focus">False</property>
                <property name="halign">center</property>
                <property name="margin-top">15</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Log in</property>
                <style>
                  <class name="login_buttons"/>
                  <class name="text_normal"/>
                </style>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">3</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

I have `main.c`:

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include "login_credentials_screen.h"

void on_button_clicked(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data);

void main(void)
{
    login_cred_subscribe_login_button_callback(on_button_clicked);
}

void on_button_clicked(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data)
{
    printf("Userdata: %s\n", data);
}
```

And `login_credentials_screen.c`:

```
GtkBuilder *login_credentials_builder;
GObject *login_credentials_screen;
GObject *user_code_entry;
GObject *company_code_entry;

void init_login_credentials_screen(void)
{
    login_credentials_builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("login_credentials_screen.ui");
    login_credentials_screen = gtk_builder_get_object(login_credentials_builder, "login_credentials_screen");
    user_code_entry = gtk_builder_get_object(login_credentials_builder, "user_code_input");
    company_code_entry = gtk_builder_get_object(login_credentials_builder, "company_code_input");

    g_signal_connect(gtk_builder_get_object(login_credentials_builder, "login_button"), "button_press_event", G_CALLBACK(on_login_button_clicked), "login_button");
    g_signal_new("login-button-clicked", G_TYPE_OBJECT, G_SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST, 0, NULL, NULL, g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__POINTER, G_TYPE_NONE, 1, G_TYPE_POINTER);
}

void login_cred_subscribe_login_button_callback(void *function)
{
    g_signal_connect(gtk_builder_get_object(login_credentials_builder, "login_button"), "login-button-clicked", G_CALLBACK(function), NULL); //NULL needs to be something else?
}

void on_login_button_clicked(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data)
{
    printf("%s\n", gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(user_code_entry)));
    printf("%s\n", gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(company_code_entry)));

    g_signal_emit_by_name(widget, "login-button-clicked", gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(company_code_entry)));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the `g_signal_connect` can be called with a variable (`char *` in this case) as `user_data` parameter, and the variable does not need to be set untill calling the `emit`.

This results in the following:

```
char user_code_string[20];

void login_cred_subscribe_login_button_callback(void *function)
{
    g_signal_connect(gtk_builder_get_object(login_credentials_builder, "login_button"), "login-button-clicked", G_CALLBACK(function), user_code_string);
}

void on_login_button_clicked(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data)
{
    strncpy(user_code_string, gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(user_code_entry)), 20);
    g_signal_emit_by_name(widget, "login-button-clicked");
}
```

Upon connecting (`g_signal_connect`) the `login-button-clicked`-signal, the variable does not need to be set.

Before emitting the signal (`g_signal_emit_by_name`), the variable can be set.

Answer (score 0):

`user_data` is NULL because it's set during connection (that null in `login_cred_subscribe_login_button_callback`) and user_data doesn't hold any of signal's data or arguments. It's ususally a way of passing "receiver" to callback, take a look at this pseudo-code example:

```c
Emitter struct{}
Receiver struct{}

emitter_emit(Emitter *self) {
    g_signal_emit(self, "name")
}

receiver_new(Emitter *emitter) {
    receiver = g_object_new(...)
    g_signal_connect (emitter, "name", G_CALLBACK(receiver_receive), receiver)
}

receiver_receive(Emitter *emitter, gpointer user_data) {
    receiver = (*Receiver)user_data;
}
```

The last argument of `g_signal_connect` is passed during the signal emission as the last argument of callback function.

Now, take a look at these lines from your code:

```c
g_signal_connect(gtk_builder_get_object(login_credentials_builder, "login_button"), "login-button-clicked", G_CALLBACK(function), NULL); // 1  
g_signal_emit_by_name(widget, "login-button-clicked", "text"); // 2
on_button_clicked(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data) // 3
```

when you emit your custom signal, the arguments are: `widget` from line 2, then `"text"` from line 2 and then `NULL` from line 1. They are passed in that order to a function which signature is on line 3 (obviously, it's wrong: the 2nd argument is not a `GdkEvent*`, it's `const char*`). Your string is in the second argument of the function.

Comment: also prefer this marshaller https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/type_func.CClosure.marshal_VOID__STRING.html